# Manim Text does not bilink. The error i get is "'c^' is not a recognized color"

Tags: python, animation, text, manim

```py
class FlashAnimationEffect(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        tex= Text("E","=","m","c^","2").scale(2)
        self.play(Write(tex))
        self.wait()
        
        self.play(Flash(tex[1],flash_radius=0.6),run_time=2)
        self.wait()
```

The Error says that 'c^' is not a recognized color. When I delete c^ the next error is the same but with "2". Thanks for your time and your answer

Comment: Please always provide a minimum reproducible work/code snippets in order to reproduce the error/problem and thus provide you some way around to solve it. 

https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `Text()` to create your text, but this object does not accept several strings as arguments (only the first one is considererd the text to render, and the others are considered other arguments, in particular the fourth one is expected to be the color, hence your error).

You probably wanted to use `Tex()` or `MathTex()`. This one works:

```py
class Test(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        tex= MathTex("E","=","m","c^","2").scale(2)
        self.play(Write(tex))
        self.wait()
        
        self.play(Flash(tex[1], flash_radius=0.6),run_time=2)
        self.wait()
```

[image: Result]

Answer (score 0):

```
class FlashAnimationEffect(Scene):
def construct(self):
    tex= Tex("E","=","m","c^","2").scale(2)
    self.play(Write(tex))
    self.wait()
    
    self.play(Flash(tex[1],flash_radius=0.6),run_time=2)
    self.wait()
```

The answer is to change Text to Tex and now it works

Comment: No, `Tex` doesn't work either because you introduced a formula not delimited by dollars. Better use `MathTex()` which uses a mathematical environment by default